# bash tab completion doesn't work on shell scripts

Tags: bash, tab-completion

On my Fedora 19 system tab completion doesn't work for bash scripts when I have a `sh` at the beginning of the command line unless the script filename ends with a `.sh`.

That is, if I type:

```
$ sh file<tab>
```

And the current directory contains:

```
filename
```

...tab completion doesn't work.

But if the current directory contains:

```
filename.sh
```

Completion works.

Completion works for everything else, so I suspect that there is a custom completer for commands that begin with `sh` and it is looking for files that end `.sh`.

Is there an easy way to fix this? I want to fix it for my user, not for all users, because I don't want to modify the operating system.

Comment: As @AlexanderPoteriachin pointed out, if you type `filename` yourself and the file is named `filename` there nothing more to complete. Do you mean you type e.g. only `filen` and `[TAB]` is not working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most basic commands to customize your completions in `bash` are:

- To only complete `.sh` files after (G stands for *globbing*):

  ```
  complete -G '*.sh' sh
  ```

  Probably this is somewhere in your (system wide) config. (You can check with `complete -pr` which prints all definitions)
- To complete *any* filename after `sh` just issue

  ```
  complete -A file sh
  ```

  `-A` takes much more possible *actions* (here: *file*), please check out the description of the `complete` builtin in `man bashbuiltins` for much more options.

For a permanent fix of that behavior, put the last command also to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: How to enable completions of current directory's files after `./` when not using `sh` command ?

Comment: @VickyDev: Although I don't fully understand what your question is, it sound like it'd better suit as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

No, there should be anything custom. Haven't seen on anything like that on any Linux version. The tab completion works as expected.

By the way, what is the point

`$ sh filename<tab>`

of that anyway if you have "filename" in your directory?

Maybe you're confused a little bit, as if you have two similar filenames in a directory, the completion only goes until the characters are the same and then it shows all available options.